# Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen Flip not detected

Tags: usb, wacom

Any ideas why flipping my pen on my Wacom Intuos Pro M does not seem to work reliably? Usually when I flip the pen the function changes from stylus to eraser. But not always. So in Gimp, or Inkscape the tool does not change when I flip the pen. Weirdness is sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

This seems to happen most often if the laptop goes into sleep mode,the longer it sleeps the more likely it is to occur. Likewise if Gimp is running when the laptop sleeps it seems more likely. Usually if it's not working in applications, it's also not working in Settings>Wacom Tablet>Test Your Settings, but not always. Sometimes the pen flip is detected in settings when it's not detected in Gimp.

Sometimes closing open apps, unplugging the Wacom and plugging it back in fixes it, sometimes it doesn't. Logging off or rebooting usually fixes it, but not always.

Reinstalled Wacom libs more times than i can count, including removing them - tip don't do that.

Disabling secure boot made no difference.

Reinstalling Gimp makes no difference, nor does resetting input devices to default.

Posted what I think could be helpful below, but if there's an event log or something else that would please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Dell G3 3779
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, 64 bit, gnome 3.36.8, kernel 5.13.0-28-generic

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger touch     id: 12  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pad pad          id: 13  type: PAD       
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen stylus       id: 14  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen eraser       id: 23  type: ERASER
```

```
$ xsetwacom --get "Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen eraser" all
Option "Area" "0 0 44800 29600"
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Option "DebugLevel" "0"
Option "CommonDBG" "0"
Option "Suppress" "2"
Option "RawSample" "4"
Option "PressCurve" "0 0 100 100"
Option "Mode" "Absolute"
Property 'Wacom Hover Click' does not exist on device.
Option "Touch" "off"
Property 'Wacom Hardware Touch Switch' does not exist on device.
Option "Gesture" "off"
Option "ZoomDistance" "0"
Option "ScrollDistance" "0"
Option "TapTime" "250"
Option "CursorProx" "10"
Option "Rotate" "none"
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Option "Threshold" "26"
Option "Serial" "0"
Option "PressureRecalibration" "on"
Option "PanScrollThreshold" "2600"
```

```
xsetwacom --get "Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen stylus" all
Option "Area" "0 0 44800 29600"
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Option "DebugLevel" "0"
Option "CommonDBG" "0"
Option "Suppress" "2"
Option "RawSample" "4" Option "PressCurve" "0 0 100 100" Option "Mode" "Absolute" Option "TPCButton" "off" Option "Touch" "off" Property 'Wacom Hardware Touch Switch' does not exist on device. Option "Gesture" "off" Option "ZoomDistance" "0"
Option "ScrollDistance" "0"
Option "TapTime" "250"
Option "CursorProx" "30"
Option "Rotate" "none"
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Option "Threshold" "26"
Option "Serial" "0"
Option "PressureRecalibration" "on"
Option "PanScrollThreshold" "2600"
```

```
DMESG[Feb 4 17:03] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ +10.881900] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.150003] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=0357, bcdDevice= 1.50
[  +0.000013] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000006] usb 1-2: Product: Wacom Intuos Pro M
[  +0.000005] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
[  +0.000004] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 7FQ00A1005223
[  +0. 009006] input: Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:10/0003:056A:0357.0006/input/input41
[  +0.000344] input: Wacom Intuos Pro M Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:056A:0357.0006/input/input43
[  +0.056922] wacom 0003:056A:0357.0006: hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Wacom Intuos Pro M] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[  +0.003288] input: Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:056A:0357.0007/input/input45
[  +0.000479] wacom 0003:056A:0357.0007: hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Wacom Intuos Pro M] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
[  +0.205267] input: Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:056A:0357.0008/input/input47
[  +0.000235] input: Wacom Intuos Pro M Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:056A:0357.0008/input/input49
[  +0.000356] wacom 0003:056A:0357.0008: hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Wacom Intuos Pro M] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
```

Comment: I've also found my Wacom tablet to misbehave a bit, starting around the same time you posted this. Un/plugging the USB sometimes fixed it momentarily. I've since upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, and now it doesn't work at all. In GIMP, when I go to Input Devices, and set stylus+eraser mode to "Screen", then they work, but they're misconfigured: stylus erases, and eraser crops. Bloody frustrating.

Comment: BTW, I did learn that if you use the stylus or the eraser, you can select a new tool, but using the stylus or eraser, not the mouse.